# select using keyword values in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to do a query in a SQLite database equivalent to this:

```
 SELECT act_unit FROM processes WHERE process='processname'
```

but using the keyword *values*, so I can specify the name, which is stored in a variable (I am actually running the query in a Jupyter notebook). I've used successfully the keyword *values* in insert statements, but I do not know how to do it here. I tried several combinations like this one

```
 SELECT act_unit from processes WHERE process=values,('processname')
```

but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

From the SQLite documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

It would be `SELECT act_unit from processes WHERE process="values",('processname')`

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There
>   are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> - 'keyword'       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
> - "keyword"       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
> - [keyword]     A
>     keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not
>     standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL
>     Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
> - `keyword`     A
>     keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.
>     This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and
>     is included in SQLite for compatibility.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. If I run it directly in SQlite browser it says _near ¨,¨ syntax error_. When I used insert statements with _values_ I did not quote the keyword, e.g: `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO equivalents (name,uuid,database_id) VALUES (?,?,0)",('name of equiv',my_uuid)`

Comment: actually what you suggest is how to use a keyword as a name, which is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to format the query string using the value of a variable.